# The CSRF protection token for the requested module is missing or invalid

Tags: typo3

I got this error, what it does it mean?

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1417988921: The CSRF protection token for the requested module is missing or invalid | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Exception thrown in file /var/www/typo3_src_elts/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Http/BackendModuleRequestHandler.php
```

And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide a code that produces the error.

Comment: the code of wich folder ? I just want to know from where the problem come, to know how what should i fix after

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is a way of protecting forms against Cross-Site Request Forgery.

As far as I remember, it appears if you clear cookies or for some old Typo3 version when you have two backend instances opened on the same Internet navigator.

Is that the case for you ?

Usually it should disappears if you log off and log in again.

Comment: i tried to log in again, but it's the same, maybe the problem came from th 2nd option you gave, but do you have any idea in which folder can i find the problem? controller for ex?

Comment: I don't know the controller or ext. Try to log off, clear the cookies and log in again.

Comment: I cleared  the coockies and it works, thank you... But i got some new errors, can you check it and help me please?    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897741/typo3-core-exception-handler-web-uncaught-typo3-exception/63897837#63897837