# TYPO3 Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception

Tags: exception, typo3

I am working on a website in TYPO3. I got some errors and I don't exactly know how to fix them.

I had the following error yesterday:

```
The page is not configured! [type=123][]. This means that there is no TypoScript object of type PAGE with typeNum=123 configured. | TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Http\ServiceUnavailableException thrown in file /var/www/typo3_src_elts/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Controller/TypoScriptFrontendController.php
```

And today I had another one:

```
Exception while property mapping at property path "": The identity property "blabla2" is no UID. | TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\Exception thrown in file /var/www/typo3_src_elts/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Property/PropertyMapper.php
```

Can someone tell me in which folder the logfiles are located, where I can see the error?

Answer (score 1):

Those are two separate issues.

The first one occurs if you call your frontend with `?type=123`. The error message already includes the issue, the requested type is not configured via TypoScript.
Either someone or something is calling your frontend with this parameter and your site doesn't know about the type. Or your site calls itself somewhere with this type, which would be an actual issue.

I would recommend to find who is calling the page, e.g. check webserver access logs for requests including the argument in the URL. Check the user agent to check if it might be some kind of bot.
In case you actually want to configure the type, check the official doc: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/10.4/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#multiple-pages

The 2nd one should come from an extension in your installation. To be more precise from an Extbase frontend plugin from within an extension. Looks like someone is again calling your frontend with the identifier "blabla2" for an object, which is invalid. Objects always have an integer as identifier. Therefore Extbase is not able to map that.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but that means that should I add "page = PAGE " in TS? i found this solution in the document you recommended above.

Comment: and the problrm is I'm a beginner with the web world, and I'm learning the typo3, but I dont have the solid base in php, so I m comfused in which file should iI add od edit the things to fix the errors, so can you tell me plz where should I search? thanks a lot

Comment: If you are completely new to this topics, I would recommend to get additional support from another agency, colleague or freelancer.
You might end up with wrong decisions and wrong assumptions and take to much time via Stack Overflow alone.

E.g. join the TYPO3 Slack and get in contact with others that might guide you. You can find further info regarding TYPO3 slack instance here: https://typo3.org/community/meet/how-to-use-slack-in-the-typo3-community